# Selecting specific components in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement bootstrap in my current code which is built over existing codebase for few years. The current codebase has several stylesheets and all.
I am using nav-pills and nav-tabs from bootstrap. However, icnluding the bootstrap.css, bootstrap.responsive.css messes up with the current layout elements like header, footer, input etc. I have tried removing some of the properties from bootstrap css files but they are over 7000 lines of code and it is not a good idea to go through every line of code in bootstrap.

Is there a version of bootstrap or way where i can select which component of bootstrap i want to use and my css files are populated accordingly. For eg i want nav-pills and nav-tabs and i believe including lal dependencies code should not be over 50-100 lines. Which is easy to debug and modify as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

https://getbootstrap.com/customize/

You can deselect the base CSS to not have it interfere.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the LESS Code from the Bootstrap GitHub Repository. Just download the latest tagged version. You also need a LESS compiler.

In addition you should first include your bootstrap file and afterwards your own stylesheets to make sure it overrides if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your 'needs' on project page.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html